# Query to extract top records by average grade and name

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am having two tables: `Movies` and `Reviews`.

`Movies` has the following columns : ID, Title, Genre, Duration;

`Reviews` has ID, Description, Movie_ID ( referencing ID from Movies) and Grade.

I would like to display a top of movies by averages.
(I would want to display the Title of the movie as well as its average grade. )

I tried with 2 subqueries : one that would select title and one that would fetch AVG from Reviews ( joined with Movies), but I can not figure out how to feed the result of the `SELECT AVG(GRADE)...` to the `SELECT TITLE FROM MOVIES ...` .
Am I trying the right way?

```
Movies

ID        TITLE          GENRE       DURATION
1         Movie_name_1   Sci-fi      120
2         Movie_name_2   Comedy      100
3         Movie_name_3   Drama       140
4         Movie_name_4   Sci-fi      105

Reviews
ID        Description    Movie_id      Grade 
1         WOW             1             10
2         SUCH            2             9
3         Great           3             9
4         Amazing         2             10
5         Decent          4             7
6         Legendary       2             10
7         Waste           3             4
8         hmmm            1             6
```

Expected Result :

```
Movie_name_1           9.50
Movie_name_2           9.25
Movie_name_3           8.25
Movie_name_4           7
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: This appears to be a simple `INNER JOIN`, `group by` and `avg()` aggregate.  What have you tried and what is not working?    No I wouldn't have two queries.  And now I don't see how your expected results match the data you have 10+6 = 16/2 =8 for movie_name_1 but you have 9.5...

Comment: I did not know I can select the AVG of Grades from Reviews in the same Select with the Title from Movies, that was confusing me.  ( the data provided was just an example to make the scope clear, didn't cater for actual avg )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, just change the `FETCH` number to however many rows you want to see:

```
SELECT Title, AVG(Grade) Grade
FROM Movies M
JOIN Reviews R on R.Movie_ID = M.ID
GROUP BY Title
ORDER BY Grade DESC
FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

*Edit: More detailed explanation below*

The basis of this query is:

```
SELECT Title, Grade
FROM Movies M
JOIN Reviews R on R.Movie_ID = M.ID
```

This gets you all of the information you need in a single result set.

Next, you want the average `Grade` per movie `Title`

This is accomplished by using the averaging function `AVG()`, and grouping by `Title` (since you want the average grade per title after all):

```
SELECT Title, AVG(Grade) Grade
FROM Movies M
JOIN Reviews R on R.Movie_ID = M.ID
GROUP BY Title
```

Note: The second `Grade` in `AVG(Grade) Grade` is just an alias.  `AVG(Grade)` doesn't have a column name otherwise, so for simplicity's sake, we are calling the new, averaged column, `Grade`.

You can also write that as `AVG(Grade) as Grade` which may be clearer to you.

Next, you want to see the most popular movies first.  We do this with an `ORDER BY`.  We can reference our averaged `Grade` column here:

```
SELECT Title, AVG(Grade) Grade
FROM Movies M
JOIN Reviews R on R.Movie_ID = M.ID
GROUP BY Title
ORDER BY Grade DESC --Referencing the averaged column, not the main column
```

Last but not least, you mentioned you want to see the top *n* rows.  We can do this with a `FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY` clause:

```
SELECT Title, AVG(Grade) Grade
FROM Movies M
JOIN Reviews R on R.Movie_ID = M.ID
GROUP BY Title
ORDER BY Grade DESC
FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

And here is one last version with a different alias name for extra clarity:

```
SELECT Title, AVG(Grade) Averaged_Grade
FROM Movies M
JOIN Reviews R on R.Movie_ID = M.ID
GROUP BY Title
ORDER BY Averaged_Grade DESC
FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: Thank you ! This solved my problem ! Can you please explain me how `AVG(Grade) Grade`   syntax works there? My confusion regarding this query was that I didn't knew I can select both Title from Movies and Avg of grades from reviews in the same Select statement, I tried to separate them in 2 selects .

Comment: @Daniel Sure thing.  Let me edit in an explanation, I'll have more space to type

Comment: @Daniel See the edit, might be more than you need but should be clear this way.  If you run each query as you go that could help too.